# Highcharts sankey diagram node representation empty space

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

I have succeeded to have in a sankey diagram multiple nodes that have the same origin and same destination with different colors:

[image]

(the first blue and first pink aim at the same, second and third too).

But I'd like to make those length proportional to some absolute value, which could be achieved by adding an extra space in the node representation:

[image]

Is this achievable?

I tried to add some links with same origin and destination, but it doesn't do what I need. :(

Thanks

Comment: Please share your live code example to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by adding a link with `outgoing: true` and `color: transparent`.

```
{
  from: this.to[0].name,
  weight: 1000000,
  color: 'transparent',
  outgoing: true,
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/18t92rg7/2/